# EF insert in link table creates entries in one of the parent tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

This is the situation:
- a table User (id, name)
- a table Role (id, name)
- a link table UsersRoles (idUser, idRole)

In the link table idUser and idRoles are FKs and BOTH of them are marked as a composite primary key.

In EF this produces the following models:

```
    public class User {
        public int ID {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public ICollection<Role> Roles {get;set;}
   }

    public class Role{
        public int ID {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public ICollection<User> Users{get;set;}
   }
```

When inserting a role to a user a strange thing happens.

```
user.Roles.Add(role);
context.SaveChanges();
```

creates an entry in the UsersRoles table AND adds a Role in the Role table. Practically it duplicates the role that i am trying to associate with a user.

Is it EF related? Is it because the FK and PK settings from the tables?

Any hint could be appreciated.

Comment: What do your data annotations or fluent APIs look like? Or is this db first?

Comment: We've used the DB first approach.

Comment: `user.Roles.Add(role);` this will add a new role to the existing user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little experimenting I found out that I was making a silly mistake. 
I was calling user.Roles.Add(role) where role was a new Role Entity, with it's id and name populated. (role = new Role(id, name))

What I needed to do was to GET an existing role from the DB records and then add it to the user. (role = dbContext.Find(id)))

Answer (score 0):

Does the role you are adding have an Id value of a role that already exists. If it only has a name then EF may add a new entry to the database.

Comment: Your answer isn't quite correct, but it pointed me in the right direction.